# ImageButton strange action

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've added 2 image buttons in my master page. Their purpose is to change the language of the site.

```
<div id="SiteHeader">
                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnBulgarian" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Default/images/bg flag.png" AlternateText="Bulgarian" OnClick="imgBtnBulgarian_Click" ValidationGroup="language" />
                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnEnglish" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Default/images/english flag.png" AlternateText="English" OnClick="imgBtnEnglish_Click" ValidationGroup="language" />
            </div>
```

This is the code behind

```
protected void imgBtnEnglish_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["language"] = "en-GB";
        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
    }

    protected void imgBtnBulgarian_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["language"] = "bg-BG";
        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
    }
```

They work just fine. The problem occur when I have some form in my Content Place Holder. For example login form. When I enter the data in the textboxes and press enter instead of clicking the login button it clicks one of the ImageButtons. When I click the login button with the mouse, it works fine. Can you help me solve this problem?

Comment: Just so you have the **why** part: This happens because the browser defaults enter to clicking the first button it finds.  See Arthur's answer for the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is, that you put your login controls in a asp:Panel and set the DefaultButton property to your login button.

*Pseudocode:*

```
<asp:Panel runat=server DefaultButton=btnLogin>
    Account: <asp:TextBox id=txtAccount ... />
    Password: <asp:TextBox id=txtAccount ... />
    <asp:Button id=btnLogin runat=server Text=Login ... />
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Correct, this is the simplest non-javascript (that you write anyway) solution.

Comment: If I nest 2 or 3 Panels can I set different DefaultButton property to each of them?